# Custom UITableViewCell getting wrong attributes when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First of all, thanks for reading my question.

I have a class with the delegate and the datasource of my UITableView. I have an array with all used data. In this class I use **2 types of cells** ("**LabelImageTableViewCell**" A simple custom cell with 1 image and 1 label & "**LabelTableViewCell**" A simple custom cell with 1 label).

I need to use a custom cell when indexpath.row == 0 and for all other cases I use another. Making use of the model when it is a **question**, I simply center the text and put it in bold. When it's an **answer**, I do not do anything.

This is the normal behavior:
[image: Normal]

This is my class:

```
import UIKit

class ServicesTableViewController: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

private let grayColor = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.95, blue:0.95, alpha:1.0)
private let grayAnswerColor = UIColor(red:0.90, green:0.90, blue:0.90, alpha:1.0)

var data = [
    ServicesModel(information: "Question 1", isHeader: true),
    ServicesModel(information: "Answer 1", isHeader: false),
    ServicesModel(information: "Question 2", isHeader: true),
    ServicesModel(information: "Answer 2", isHeader: false)        
]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LabelImageTableViewCell.cellType, for: indexPath) as? LabelImageTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            cell.displayInformation(title: "services_and_hours".localized(), img: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ServicesPhoto"))
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LabelTableViewCell.cellType, for: indexPath) as? LabelTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            if data[indexPath.row - 1].isHeader {
                cell.informationLabel.textAlignment = .center
                cell.informationLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
                cell.displayInformation(data[indexPath.row - 1].information, (textColor: .black, backgroundColor: grayAnswerColor))
            } else {
                cell.displayInformation(data[indexPath.row - 1].information, (textColor: .black, backgroundColor: grayColor))
            }
            return cell
        } 
    }    
}
```

> And my problem is that when I scroll, the text that is answer is suddenly aligned to the middle as if it were a question.

This is the strange behavior:

[image: Strange]

Answer (score 3):

> When it's an answer, I do not do anything.

And that’s exactly the problem. Cells are reused. So the answer cell was once a question cell. And you do nothing to make it stop looking like a question.

You are saying

```
cell.informationLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

in the if case. But you never say to align left in the else case. Therefore when a centered cell is reused it just stays centered.

Similarly for bold and not bold.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you setting the **textAlignment** for `isHeader` but you are not setting any alignment for non-header cell. Since the same type of cell is reused, you need to set all the properties in both (`if` and `else`). please see below:

```
if data[indexPath.row - 1].isHeader {
    cell.informationLabel.textAlignment = .center
    cell.informationLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    cell.displayInformation(data[indexPath.row - 1].information, (textColor: .black, backgroundColor: grayAnswerColor))
} else {
    cell.informationLabel.textAlignment = .left
    cell.informationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
    cell.displayInformation(data[indexPath.row - 1].information, (textColor: .black, backgroundColor: grayColor))
}
```